# Changed the alias of cd command by mistake

Tags: alias, tcsh

I changed the alias for `cd` command by mistake. The default alias for `cd` was `chdir !* && setprompt` before I changed it to some random command by mistake. I tried changing it back to `chdir !* && setprompt` by using the command `alias cd 'chdir !* && setprompt'`. When I run alias command, I see that the alias for `cd` is not what I had set. It is `chdir  && setprompt` instead of `chdir !* && setprompt`. `!*` is missing. Why doesn't it get changed to what I gave? How do I revert to the default alias of `cd` command. I'm using `tcsh` shell.

Comment: Escape the `!`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I didn't know about those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need escape the exclamation mark, This will work:

```
alias cd 'chdir \!* setprompt'
```

as a note !* will be converted to the command line parameters of the previous command so in your case whatever command you had run before setting the alias had no parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your note. The note helped me understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unalias command to remove the new alias for the cd command:

```
unalias cd
```